# JAX-RS Resources Monitoring

Tags: monitoring, jax-rs

I'd like to monitor an Java EE 6 application that is composed of JAX-RS resources (ejbs with JAX-RS annotations). I want to know, for instance, how many requests were made in some period and the time it took for each request to be completed (and the result). How can I do that?

For now I thought on writing an Interceptor that records each EJBs invocation in a RRDTool storage for posterior analisys. But, by doing this I won't be able to get the request information.

Also I've read about JMX, but coudn't find anything related to webservices (JAX-RS specifically).

Is there any tool or library that helps on doing this? If not, how can I develop it? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAX-RS has the beauty that requests go over HTTP, so if you can get the at the HTTP stats, you basically have the JAX-RS stats.

In [RHQ](http://rhq-project.org/) we are doing this by injecting a filter into the servlet to gather the stats, dump them to a logfile in a format we can consume and then later read the logfile and inject the data into our metric collection.